# Canadian and PayPal account linked to US bank

Tags: united-states, canada, banking, paypal

If a Canadian citizen has a US fund bank account in Canada, can they open a PayPal account and link the US fund bank account to it? They will not have a US address since they only have the US bank account for travel purposes. What fees will they be charged if they send money to a US relative's PayPal account?

Comment: Please explain to us Americans who don't regular deal with Canadian  banks what a `US fund bank account` is.

Comment: It means they have a separate  account for depositing & withdrawing American dollars. Mostly used for travel to the U.S. so they can take advantage of better exchange rates and not have to exchange currency many times.

Comment: This is the kind of question I'd ask on the PayPal help forum.